# How to detect a lambda in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

A surrogate can be defined to complicate detection - code below. Do lambdas have a more distinguishing property?

---

**Code**:

```py
import types

def is_lambda(obj):
    return ("<lambda>" == getattr(obj, '__name__', '') and
            isinstance(obj, types.LambdaType))
```

**Test**:

```py
import functools 

def func():
    return 1

def not_lambda():
    return 2

class A():
    afunc = func
    def __init__(self):
        self.bfunc = func

a = A()
A_afunc = A.afunc
A_bfunc = a.bfunc

lambd = lambda x: x
functools.wraps(lambda: 1)(not_lambda).__name__
```

```py
def test(obj, expected):
    if is_lambda(obj) is expected:
        print("Correctly   identified", obj, "as", "lambda" if expected else "not lambda")
    else:
        print("Incorrectly identified", obj, "as", "not lambda" if expected else "lambda")

test(func,       False)
test(A_afunc,    False)
test(A_bfunc,    False)
test(not_lambda, False)
test(lambd,      True)
```

```
Correctly   identified <function func at 0x000001EE3F969CA8> as not lambda
Correctly   identified <function func at 0x000001EE3F969CA8> as not lambda
Correctly   identified <function func at 0x000001EE3F969CA8> as not lambda
Incorrectly identified <function <lambda> at 0x000001EE3FBD2288> as lambda
Correctly   identified <function <lambda> at 0x000001EE3FB1D708> as lambda
```

Comment: `types.LambdaType` won't give you just lambda functions, but any function. Why do you even need to know this? Really, just checking if it is a function type and it's name is `'<lambda>'` is the only way, AFAIKT.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Context [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/242109/get-methods-in-module-python)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga More context [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/242092/multiple-inheritance-of-class-broken-up-into-modules); point isn't "why", but "can it be done and how".

Comment: You already have a way for it to be done.  There is noting that really distinguishes lambda functions from regular functions, once the function object is created.